# How do i fix NTL PowerMod issue

Tags: c++

ZZ PowerMod(const ZZ& a, const ZZ& e, const ZZ& n)

I did the following

ZZ a,b,c;

a=13;
b=1;
c=11;

ZZ result;

result = PowerMod(a,b,c);

I tried to compile and run, it say PowerMod error , bad args.

It only accept long,long,long and return long type.. but issue is I did use PowerMod with ZZ on my previous other cpp file and its fine.

```
void PowerMod(ZZ& x, const ZZ& a, const ZZ& e, const ZZ& n);
ZZ PowerMod(const ZZ& a, const ZZ& e, const ZZ& n);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but I'll leave an answer so anyone stumbling along looking for an answer will find one.

According to this:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?506099-NTL-problem

a must be smaller than n. I don't know if that is your problem, but I would try:
PowerMod(a % n, e, n)